# Android/Gradle: Why is it possible to declare several times the values.XML file?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

### Pre-requisites

I have created an application in which the following tree structure is used (the app-level build.gradle being modified according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#change_your_resource_directory) - you can find these changes at the end of this question):

- app

  - src

    - main

      - my_theme

        - bundles

          - a_bundle

            - drawable folder, values folder, layout folder, etc.
        - global

          - drawable folder, values folder, layout folder, etc.

There are several bundles. All the values directories (one per bundle and one in the global folder) contain the file `strings.XML`. **My application does compile and execute correctly**.

However, the Android documentation states that:

> Note: If two or more resource directories contain the same resource file, an error occurs during resource merging.

(https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#change_your_resource_directory)

### Question

So, since I use the same file `strings.xml` , why no error is shown? (of course, the content of these `strings.xml` files changes according to the directory in which they are located - either their bundle directory, or the global directory)

**app-level build.gradle**

To make it work (eg. to make the Android Resolver able to resolve symbols), I added these lines:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/bestheme/global',
                'src/main/bestheme/bundles/a_bundle'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strings.xml` (and any `values` resources) are different in the sense that resource identifiers are not based on file names but are actually specified inside the files.

Resource merging occurs on resource identifier level. If there are no conflicts in resource identifiers on the same sourceset level, then the merger works all right.

The documentation notes are valid for resource types where resource id is derived from the filename. For example, layout or drawable resources.

Comment: Clear answer, thanks! Where did you learn that? Btw, do you think my tree structure would cause any development problem? *(I have read that having different drawable folders were only censed to handle different screens sizes for example, but this isn't what I'm doing here)* - Or even worse: could my tree structure imply bugs at the execution of my app in customers' phone?

Comment: This is based on my practical experience with Android build tools, and accepting that documentation is not always 100% accurate.